# How to keep children's state while change the parent component tree / structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Now, change the value of `m` (`TheDemo`'s state), the structure of component tree changed, and the `v` (`TheChild`'s state) will reset to init value `3`.

What I want is: while change the value of `m`, keep the value of `v` unchanged.

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-waterfall-if1v0z?file=/index.js

```
import React, { StrictMode, useState } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

function TheDemo() {
  const [m, setM] = useState(true);
  const child = <TheChild />;
  return (
    <div style={{ fontFamily: "monospace" }}>
      <button onClick={() => setM(!m)}>m = {+m}</button>
      {m ? <b>{child}</b> : <span>{child}</span>}
    </div>
  );
}

function TheChild() {
  const [v, setV] = useState(3);
  return <button onClick={() => setV(v + 1)}>v = {v}</button>;
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <TheDemo />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Maybe this a X-Y problem? The origin problem is I want to allow user to change page layout , move a child_0 from parent_1 to parent_2.

> The demo is simplified, I have a lot of nested children components and lift up all state is nearly impossible.

> Tao's comment solved this question, and the [react docs link here](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state).

Comment: Either lift the state in the parent component as suggested in @M.Hav's answer or keep the same DOM element (e.g: `<span style={ m ? {fontWeight: 'bold'} : null }>{child}</span>`).

Comment: Consider reading [Preserving and Resetting State](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state).

Comment: @tao's answer is your problem. You are changing the tree structure that React uses to store state. You either need to lift the state, or not impact the tree. Another way to look at the same code is changing your line 10 to be: `{m ? child : child}`... switching between `<b>` and `<span>` gives a different UI tree, so React throws the state away and redraws.

Comment: Thanks to @tao and dan-bowling . I will try to use css grid to change the layout. And why not post as the answer so I can mark this solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in [Preserving and Resetting State](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state), React associates a component's state with its position in DOM and its HTML tag (or, in more general terms, with the DOM tree structure). If one of those changes, the state is reset in the changed branches ***<sup>1</sup>***. In your case, the position is kept, but the HTML tag is changed.

The simplest way to fix it (in this case) would be to keep the HTML `<span>` tag and change its `style` from `{}` (or `null`) to `{ fontWeight: 'bold' }` based on `m`'s truthiness:

```
<span style={ m ? {fontWeight: 'bold'} : null }>{child}</span>
```

---

If you're looking for a more generic mechanism (and this was just a simplified example), you have several other options to persist state in React:

- lift the state into a parent component which doesn't re-render when `m` changes and pass the state down through props
- use [React.context](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext). Same principle as lifting state, except you can access the state using a hook no matter how many levels deep, without having to do prop drilling (adding the prop to each intermediary parent)
- use a state management solution. Jotai, Recoil, XState, Redux, Rematch, Zustand (the list is not comprehensive). I've placed Jotai first because you literally just need to replace `React.useState()` with `Jotai.useAtom()` and you're good to go ***<sup>2</sup>***.
  All state management solutions have a way to set a boundary on the context using that state (typically a Provider), so you can have multiple instances of the same state (e.g: in a list rendering example, where you'd want each list item and all of its children to use their own context).

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - there is an exception: you can change the position in DOM without losing state by using `:key` (and keeping the same tag/component)
***<sup>2</sup>*** - at least in the case you presented; more complex data sharing might require more complex solutions; I'd say Jotai is good at hiding its own complexity, but does have a few gotchas.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the value of `v` unchanged while changing the value of `m`, you can lift the state of `TheChild` component up to the `TheDemo` component and pass it down as props. Here's the modified code:

```js
import React, { StrictMode, useState } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

function TheDemo() {
  const [m, setM] = useState(true);
  const [v, setV] = useState(3); // Lift the state up
  const child = <TheChild v={v} setV={setV} />; // Pass the state down as props
  return (
    <div style={{ fontFamily: "monospace" }}>
      <button onClick={() => setM(!m)}>m = {+m}</button>
      {m ? <b>{child}</b> : <span>{child}</span>}
    </div>
  );
}

function TheChild({ v, setV }) { // Receive the state from props
  return <button onClick={() => setV(v + 1)}>v = {v}</button>;
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <TheDemo />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Now, when you change `m`, the value of `v` will remain unchanged because it's managed by the parent component `TheDemo`. This way, you can also change the page layout while keeping the state of child components unchanged.

Comment: Actually, the demo is simplified, in detail, I have a lot of children components and lift up state is nearly impossible. I will edit the question for more infos.